# GMOD CS:S wont work

Tags: 15.10, steam

i have downloaded CS:S textures from cs cheater and put them in .steam\steam\steamapp\common\garrysmod\addons but it still wont work, i am running ubuntu 15.10 if you were wondering

Comment: Do they work when you create a local server ?

Answer (score 0):

the css addon file had capital letters so i gave it a name (i actually named it "name") that only had lowercase letters and now it works. i found the answer by removing almost all key words and typing in "gmod css linux" on youtube.